# How to convert "for of" in classic JavaScript to jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not very familiar with classic JavaScript, so how would this lines look like at jQuery?

```
const siemas = document.querySelectorAll('.slider');

for(const siema of siemas) {
    new Siema({
    selector: siema
});
}
```

This ...

```
const siemas = document.querySelectorAll('.slider');
```

.. will be just (if I am right):

```
var siemas = $('.slider');
```

And this ...

```
for(const siema of siemas)
```

... will become somethink like:

```
$.each ???
```

Comment: It seems that you think that vanilla JavaScript is somehow "classic" and jQuery is "modern". I'd argue that it's the other way around.

Comment: Why would you do that? People tend to do the opposite, get rid of jQuery (which is really just a Javascript toolbox) rather than converting vanilla JS into jQuery. There are even tutorials and websites like [youmightnotneedjquery](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) to help getting rid of jQuery. It's not a bad library, far from it, but JS has evolved over time and doesn't really need jQuery anymore

Comment: OK, I dont wanna annoying someone ;) and you are right. I have just the problem, that some "old browsers" can not convert "for of", if I am right?

Comment: Of course, guess who [doesn't support](https://caniuse.com/?search=for%20of) `for...of`...?

Comment: @Jeremy Thille Good to know - thx for the info link.

Comment: IE is out of support since a year already, devs should stop to support it as well

Comment: @Cid that is most of the time out of the developer's hands. The company they work for may insist on it being supported. So they can use Babel if they must

Comment: I agree but businesses have to cater for their market, and in many cases large portions of their (international) market are still using IE. At least that was the case with China a few years ago. I don't know if things have changed recently, but iirc around 70% of our (old job) Chinese market was still bound to IE. @Cid

Comment: @Andy they were greedy users of ActiveX?

Comment: No idea. We eventually just used graceful degradation to just supply a very minimal IE experience to them. Yes we should be encouraging all new developers to embrace the most modern forms of JS, but as @mplungjan said, a lot of the time this is taken out of our hands by project managers stamping on our creativity forever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have multiple slide shows

- **for..of vs simple for loop**

  ```
  const sliders = document.querySelectorAll('.slider');
  for (let i=0;i<sliders.length;i++) {
    new Siema({
      selector: sliders[i]
    });
  }
  ```
- **for..of vs forEach**

for..of is not supported by IE, but you can use a forEach instead. The forEach needs to be wrapped using spread since IE also does not support forEach on an HTML collection

```
  [...document.querySelectorAll('.slider')].forEach(function() {
    new Siema({
      selector: this
    });
  })
```

- **for..of vs jQuery each**

  ```
  $('.slider').each(function() {
    new Siema({
     selector: this
    })
  })
  ```
- **perhaps (depending on your html) you can just do**

  ```
  const slideShow = new Siema({
    selector: '.slider'
  })
  ```

Comment: Thx for your support! Looks good.

Comment: `selector: "#"+this.id` - the [Siema documentation](https://pawelgrzybek.github.io/siema/) says "**selector** (string or DOM element)" - so `selector: this` would work

Comment: @Tomalak thanks - I was wondering  about that. `selector` is for me a css/jQuery selector. I updated the code

Answer (score 3):

In jquery.

```
var siemas = $('.slider');
siemas.each(function(){
    // this represent current element
    new Siema({
        selector: this
    });
});
```

Comment: Also thx for your support.

Comment: yes, i misunderstood this question at first.

Comment: Hehe, no problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

for..of is a widely available cycle, which is supported by all browsers, except the now deprecated IE. So, in jQuery you would do

```
$('slider').each(function() {
    //this is the 'current' slider element
    //$(this) is the jQuery object of the current slider
});
```

But it is not really advisable to increase depedency of jQuery, a technology that JS no longer needs just to support it. Instead, you could simply use your for..of loops while you write your code and use BabelJS to convert your code to ES5 so that IE will be able to cope with it. [Example](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&corejs=3.6&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=G4QwTgBOkLwQ2gRgDQQEyoMwF0DcAofAMwHtIAKAGwFMAXCAS1uoFsISiowwBKCAb3wRhEAPSiAJiQgB3ABYhmwapBlM5jZi3wBfIA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Cstage-1&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.15.8&externalPlugins=&assumptions=%7B%7D):

Converts

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
for (let item of arr) {
    //do whatever with item
}
```

into

```
"use strict";
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
for (var _i = 0, _arr = arr; _i < _arr.length; _i++) {
    //do whatever with item
    var item = _arr[_i];
}
```

So, you can implement myscript.js and using Babel you can generates its [ES5](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_es5.asp) version, let's call it myscript_ie.js. So, when your page is loaded, you can check whether the browser is IE. If not, then you can load your normal script. Otherwise you can load your IE version.

**The reason for this specific recommendation is that for..of is only one of the features IE does not support, this answer aims to solve all these incompatibilities, or at least to greatly reduce them and goes beyond the problem of for..of**